# Using Today() function in a query with standard dates in Google Sheets

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am working with data output from a program and then uploaded into google sheets that looks like the  following:

[image: Data in google sheet]

So my timestamp is in the format of 1/2/2020 8:56 (and I totally get that query has to work with yyyy-mm-dd format, which is why we have to do the acrobatics)

I'm using the query function to pull needed data into different tabs and would like to use the Today() or Now() function to only pull the last 12 or 24 hours results and I can't seem to get it to work. (Mind that I'm just learning the query function)

So I have

`=query(RawDataUpload!A:I,"select * where A is not null and A >= date '2020-01-02' and B = 'Buying' and H > 0 and H < 50000 Order by D, H desc")`

and it works ok, but I have to put in the date each new day and at 8am it's only 8 hours of data instead of 12 (more of a problem at 2am)

I've tried using a few examples and I keep getting a parsing error or some error

```
=query(RawDataUpload!A:I,"select * where A is not null and A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1 and B = 'Buying' and H > 0 and H < 50000 Order by D, H desc")")


=query(RawDataUpload!A:I,"select * where A is not null and A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'" and B = 'Buying' and H > 0 and H < 50000 Order by D, H desc")")
```

[I see & thrown in but no explanation of why or what it does, and same to the " " instead of ' ' and why the mix mash of using both in the examples of using today() and I've found 0 examples of using the now instead of the date function in my googling.]

So is there a way to limit by date (and possibly time) using the today() or Now()-12 function embedded in the Query function in google sheets?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet if answers bellow are not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(RawDataUpload!A:I,"select * where A is not null and A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B = 'Buying' and H > 0 and H < 50000 Order by D, H desc")
```

The `&` is used to join a string to form a formula.

For example, if you want the formula to read:

```
... and A >= date '2020-01-03' and B =....
```

But you'd like the date to be today's date, you would use:

```
...and A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B =...
```

The `"` is used to exit the query string and add the `Text()` formula. And the `&` is used to join them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filter like this:

```
= filter ( A2:I,B2:B="Buying", 
           text(A2:A,"yyyy.mm.dd.hh")>=text(now(),"yyyy.mm.dd.") & "08",
           text(A2:A,"yyyy.mm.dd.hh")<=text(now()+0,"yyyy.mm.dd.") & "16"
         )
```

begin from row 2 because in row 1 are column titles

Remarks1 : 08 & 16 are for limit hour begin from 08 and last 16, can be changed

Remarks2 : +0 only this day, if change to +1 this day and tomorrow and so on